# ¿Cómo cargar imágenes de un servidor y cambiar de imagen con una seekbar sin que desaparezca la imagen anterior?

Tags: java, android, imagen, animación, picasso

Me ha encargado la Universidad Autónoma de Barcelona hacer una app que muestra imágenes de la platina de microscopio de una muestra mineral.

En concreto tengo fotos de la misma muestra espaciadas por un giro de cinco grados (72 imágenes).
[Se descargan de la web de la UAB](https://ddd.uab.cat/record/190567?ln=ca).

Debajo de la imagen tiene que haber una seekbar y que se vayan cargando las imágenes según se mueva esta dando la impresión de que la platina del microscopio está girando.

Lo he intentado con Picasso:

```
public class FichaOpacos extends AppCompatActivity {
private String urlParalelos;
private ImageView platina;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ficha_opacos);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    Database myDb = new Database(this);
    String mineral = myDb.getMineral(id);
    platina = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.platina);
    urlParalelos = myDb.getURL1(mineral);
    myDb.closeDatabase();
    String urlInicialParalelos= urlParalelos+ "1.jpg";
    Picasso.get().load(urlInicialParalelos).into(platina);
    SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seek);
    seekBar.setProgress(0);
    seekBar.incrementProgressBy(1);
    seekBar.setMax(71);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String urlFinalParalelos = urlParalelos+ String.valueOf(progress+1) + ".jpg";
            Picasso.get().load(urlFinalParalelos).into(platina);

        }
    });


}
}
```

El problema es que en la transición entre imágenes desaparece la imagen y después a los milisegundos aparece la siguiente, no dando la impresión de que se está viendo una platina de microscopio girando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría obtener el efecto deseado?

Me imagino que necesito una animación que mantenga la imagen anterior hasta que se muestre la imagen siguiente, pero no he trabajado nunca con animaciones y no sabría cómo implementarlo.

Answer (score 3):

La solución que he encontrado y que genera el resultado esperado es descargar las 72 imágenes al inicio de la actividad.

De este modo las imágenes están disponibles y se cargan rápido y parece que la platina de microscopio gira.

El único inconveniente es que el usuario ha de esperar unos segundos al cargar la actividad.

```
public class FichaOpacos extends AppCompatActivity {
private String urlParalelos;
private ImageView platina;
private ArrayList<Drawable> imagenes;
private ProgressDialog progress;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ficha_opacos);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    Database myDb = new Database(this);
    String mineral = myDb.getMineral(id);
    platina = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.platina);
    urlParalelos = myDb.getURL1(mineral);
    myDb.closeDatabase();
    String urlInicialParalelos = urlParalelos + "1.jpg";
    Picasso.get().load(urlInicialParalelos).into(platina);
    SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seek);
    seekBar.setProgress(0);
    seekBar.incrementProgressBy(1);
    seekBar.setMax(71);
    imagenes = new ArrayList<>();
    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Loading images....");
    progress.show();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //doing long task
            try {
                for(int i= 0 ;i < 72; i++) {
                    imagenes.add(drawableFromUrl(urlParalelos + String.valueOf(i + 1) + ".jpg"));
                    float tantoporuno = (float)(i+1)/(float)72;
                    int porcentaje = Math.round(tantoporuno*100);
                    progress.setMessage("Loading..." + String.valueOf(porcentaje) + "%");
                    if (i==71) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    platina.setImageDrawable(imagenes.get(progress));
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}
public static Drawable drawableFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
    Bitmap x;
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(), x);
}
}
```

Comment: Si necesitas mostrar 72 imágenes obtenidas de manera remota y sin que exista un "parpadeo" entre ellas... la única manera es mover todos esos "parpadeos" al inicio. Las imágenes tienes que descargarlas, no te queda otra :) Puedes intentar hacerlo en paralelo para ahorrar un poco de tiempo (en vez de descargarlas una a una, descargas varias a la vez con múltiples hilos), pero siempre vas a tener que esperar a tenerlas todas, no hay otra manera :)

Comment: @Benito-B les he puesto un link a esto en el grupo de whatsapp. Gracias por corroborar lo que pensaba. Lo que vamos a hacer es que cargue la ficha con las propiedades del mineral y una sola imágen. Y que al mover la seekbar por primera vez sea cuando descargue las imágenes y el estudiante tenga que esperar unos segundos.

Comment: Hay varias cosas que puedes hacer para reducir el tiempo de carga como asegúrarte de que las imágenes estén optimizadas (usar jpg en vez de png para reducir el peso, ajustar la calidad y el tamaño. Diría también usar webP, que ofrece mejor rendimiento que jpg incluso, aunque los modelos más viejos de IOS no son compatibles con este formato) o descárgarlas en paralelo (aumenta la complejidad del código pero puede reducir significativamente el tiempo de carga).

Comment: @Benito-B Las imágenes están almacenadas como jpg en el servidor de la UAB. Luego es que la calidad es importante para estos estudiantes de grado (es su proyecto), porque al girar la platina se ven matices como el pleocroísmo, cambia sutilmente de color el mineral. La app va a dar la opción de descargar las imágenes desde ajustes y trabajar sin conexión, pero me han pedido que la app subida no almacene las imágenes (son 72x60), que ocuparía bastante en la memoria interna.